# A number theory problem concerning effects of shifting digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find a positive integer whose first digit is 1 and which has the property that, if this digit is transferred to the end of the number, the number is tripled.

A full proof will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Two aproaches:

Often, and here, you can just construct it.  You want $$3\cdot \overline {1abcd\ldots}=\overline{abcd\ldots 1}$$
You can see the last digit is $7$, so write it in on the right and find the next to last digit.  Keep going until you find a $1$ on the left.  Once you find one solution, you can repeat it as many times as you want.

Write your number as $10^n+b$ where $b$ has $n$ digits.  Then the requirement is $$3\cdot(10^n+b)=10b+1\\7b=10^n-1$$
so find an $n$ so that $10^n-1$ is a multiple of $7$

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I trust you found that $n = 6, 12, 18, \ldots$ or $6 k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.